# Client credentials not retrived when attempting to use aws php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, wamp, credentials

I am attempting to connect to a `DynamoDB` hosted on `aws` using `php`.

I am currently getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException'
>   with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile
>   metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1000
>   milliseconds  (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))'  in
>   C:\wamp\www\Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 79

I've taken this to mean there are issues with my client `credentials` which I need to use the `sdk`. My `credentials` are coded as follows:

```
$client = new DynamoDbClient([
'profile' => 'my profile',
'region'  => 'us-west-2',
'version' => 'latest',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => 'my key',
    'secret' => 'my secret key',
    ]
]);
```

From what I've seen this error usually means there is a problem with the way the `credentials` are formatted, but as far as I can tell I don't have that issue. I'm currently trying to run this program locally using `wamp`. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like you should be doing this a different way, e.g. `$client = DynamoDbClient::factory([argshere])` and lose the "credentials" array, so key and secret are just part of the main args - [see the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/configuration.html#client-configuration-options) and [here as well](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with that format unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps and check if it work correctly :

1) Download aws php sdk [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/download/aws.zip).

2) Unzip and require autoloader.php and use dynamodb client.

```
require_once 'PATH/TO/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
```

3) initiate dynamo db client

```
try
{
    $aws = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
                        'key'    => $aws_key,
                        'secret' => $aws_access_key,
                        'region' => $aws_region
                ));

    echo "Client initiated";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Db Client initiation failed ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

4) [Check this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_factory) for api's

Comment: I get "Client initiated" echoed back but my program is still hitting the same error in 'Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php'.

Comment: This error lies in C:\wamp\www\Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php. Whats the need of this script if my code runs successfully?

Comment: Found the issue, I was looking for errors in the wrong place. The dynamoDB credentials were fine, the issue was I hadn't also defined credentials for the sdk itself.

Comment: Great! Solved bug your own. Appreciated.